# Where are dictionary keys() set operations documented?

Tags: python

I wanted to know why set operations on dict keys views work only as operators:

```
>>> d = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
>>> s = {'c', 'd', 'e'}

>>> d.keys() - s
{'a', 'b'}

>>> d.keys().difference(s)
AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'difference'
```

Do you know the answer or could you point me to the right source?

I could find some limited documentation in the old 3.0 docs:

https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

but not in the recent version:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping-> https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the dictionary view docs you linked:

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable. If all values are hashable, so that (key, value) pairs are unique and hashable, then the items view is also set-like. (Values views are not treated as set-like since the entries are generally not unique.) For set-like views, all of the operations defined for the abstract base class [collections.abc.Set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Set) are available (for example, ==, <, or ^).

And if you go to the `collections.abc` docs and scroll to the [table](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) showing all the methods, you'll see that `collections.abc.Set` specifies only the operator forms of set operations. For example, `__sub__` is listed, but not `difference`.